# How to get a foreground colour on a pivot object

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, spfx

I have a row of pivot buttons which I use for my spfx form in a web part. I need to be able to give a grey background when users hover over the control. so at the moment my control looks like this :

[image]

So the blue bar changes on select but I want a grey hover over so the users know where to click.

Thanks in advance.

I have written this code to get the style but I cannot add the style into the component:

```
const styler  = {
root: [
{
selectors: {
':hover': {
 background: '#2C3539'
}
}
}
]
};
```

Comment: Any help on here ?

Answer (score 0):

In this [codepen](https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/ZNQVXL) you can see how you can pass styles to the correct style areas for Pivot control.

```
link: [
    !rootIsTabs && {
      selectors: {
        ':hover': {
          backgroundColor: palette.neutralLighter,
          color: palette.neutralDark
        },
        ':active': {
          backgroundColor: palette.neutralLight
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

To mention also, is that the styles I demo will be default styles in the next major release (Fabric v7), so you can have this in your code until we have an official release (within a few weeks) and when you have the ability to upgrade you can remove it and have it backed in into the component.

P.S.: the animation is another bonus that comes with this new major release.

Comment: really helpful but I am getting Property 'styles' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IPivotProps'.ts(2322) - when I enter the styles in the pivot command

Comment: This can mean only one thing... the version of `office-ui-fabric-react` they use is old and perhaps the `Pivot` was not converted to css-in-js in that version. Can you look what version they use so I can verify and confirm my theory. If it is like I said I might still try and help you out but need a version number they use.

Comment: looking at the package.json this is the version we are on :  "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.7.1",

Comment: This looks like a custom bundle coming from the spfx framework and it doesn't really tell me the version of the `office-ui-fabric-react` they or you are using. But I did see the error you mentioned before and it usually points to an outdated version.